# Why both the function calls return the same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See the code segment below:

```
var o = {f:function(){ return this.a + this.b; }};
var p = Object.create(o);
o.a = 10;
o.b = 20;

console.log(o.f());  // output: 30
console.log(p.f());  // output: 30
```

The object *p* doesn't have property *p.a* and *p.b* then how *p.f()* return output 30. Is that prototype chain? Could anyone explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes..just check the console here http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/azjmxasu/

Comment: You can see `a` and `b` on the `__proto__` property of `p`

Comment: Yes, it's the protootype chain. You can avoid it by shadowing `a` and `b`: `p.a = p.b = 5; p.f() === 10`

Comment: To avoid that you can use `var p = jQuery.extend({},o);` in jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here `o` is the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of the `p` object, so all the propeties of `o` is available in `p`.

So when you call `p.f()`, you will get the values assigned to `o` in `this.a` and `this.b`